# "Turn slightly right" or "Turn slight right"

Tags: expressions, adjectives, adverbs

This is a grammatical question. For a route navigation, which expression is better to say? 
"slight" is adjective and "slightly" is adverb, so I guess "Turn slightly right" would be the correct in this case. But I do not hear the phrase so often.
Anybody knows the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turn slightly right* is grammatical  since as you said, 'slightly' is an adverb. However, most navigation apps I have used say ***Make*** a slight right. Which is also grammatically correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Good to know that both are grammatically correct and "Make a slight right" is rather general in use. I will consider your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***"Bear right"*** (e.g. *at the fork*) is what a native speaker of English would be more likely to say.